# Python Flask waits to finish Thread before responding

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have a flask webserver with a route that needs to keep computing after giving the response. To accomplish this, I created a route that starts a Thread when is called and inmediatly gives a response, to confirm that the request was recived, while the thread runs the long complex method. The idea is that the response doesnt need to wait to finish the computing algorithm I programed on the Thread, but its not working as I expected:

```
@app.route('/runThreadTest', methods = ['POST'])

def return_status():
  
    Thread(target = runThread()).start()
    print("lets see when this sentence is printed")

    return ("Response")    

def runThread():

    print("started thread")
    time.sleep(10)

    return print("finished thread")
```

The output expected is:

```
started thread
Lets see when this sentence is printed
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2022 12:49:08] "POST /runThreadTest HTTP/1.1" 200 -
finished thread
```

But the obtained output is:

```
started thread
finished thread
lets see when this sentence is printed
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2022 12:49:08] "POST /runThreadTest HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Which makes no sense to me. Why does it wait to finish the thread to give me a response?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was sintactical in this line:

```
Thread(target = runThread()).start()
```

The correct way to create a thread is:

```
Thread(target = runThread).start()
```

Comment: this problem was so many times in similar questions.

Comment: This comment serves little to no help. Please, save your comments for when you have the knowledge or intention to help. @furas

Comment: comments don't have to be so helpful like answers. They can only inform about something.